Suspicious downvote pattern—possible voting abuse?
Is there voting abuse currently going on? Almost every post, both questions and answers, posted yesterday until currently has at least one downvote:

Trying to find a French film I watched 5-10 years ago on Netflix -  The question has at least one downvote.
What is the live-action WWII film G.I. Robot was watching in Creature Commandos S01E03? - The question and both answers have at least one downvote.
Old black and white movie/TV show with lobsters committing suicide -  Has at least one downvote.
Is there any significance to the bird flying into Shelby's face in "It's What's Inside"? - Both the question and the answer have at least one downvote.
Is there a reason that the McCallister house has a doggie door? -  The question and answer have at least one downvote.
Can anyone explain these hand signals in Black Hawk Down? - The question has at least one downvote.

And on top of this, it appears most, if not all, ID questions have also received at least one downvote.
I'm hoping the moderators can take a look into this (and escalate it to the Stack Exchange staff if necessary). Could this be a case of voting system abuse? I'd appreciate it if we could get some eyes on this and figure out what's going on.

I've noticed systematic downvoting of my answers over the past few days and flagged it for moderator review. One single downvote for each answer, typically at (roughly) the same time each day.

I'll voluntarily admit that my question about the McCallister doggie door was motivated by boozy eggnog and I should have investigated it closer before posting. It probably deserved the downvote.

Serial targeted downvoting is caught by the system quite well.  Generalized downvoting is not, after all people are entitled to a negative opinion, but I agree this seems systemic and not related to the quality of posts. I'll see if there's anything I can do.

Hmm, I got several downvotes worth of rep back with a "user removed" notification, suggesting that our culprit (or at least one of them) has been caught.

I had +4 reputation today for the same reason and my recent downvote has disappeared.  I know of a user that deleted their account, I believe in response to a short suspension they received (unrelated to voting). If they are indeed the source of some of the indiscriminate downvotes, and the time of the deletion and the reputation changes do align,  I guess we won't miss them.

Looks like the user who was doing this has/was deleted so their votes on posts have been reversed.

@iandotkelly - I got 18 back. I guess I had 9(!) downvotes from the same person in the space of a couple of days.

Interesting to see several downvotes on this meta post. Are the downvoters suggesting that the pattern I've noticed isn't actually suspicious?

@galacticninja To be honest, I think by now you've fallen into the same trap as many avid meta users (including many moderators) and some people might just start to get annoyed by what they perceive as constant bickering on meta. This might not be a fair judgment of your site engagement by these people, but noone said any of this was fair. Unfortunately, though, there's hardly a way out of this if you feel you need to call out what you perceive as genuine issues. People telling you "maybe chill for moment" aren't any more helpful than you asking "why you downvote me?" to the anonymous public.

@NapoleonWilson Calling this 'bickering' feels off. I’m just pointing out what looks like a pattern of vote abuse, with systematic downvotes on multiple posts. I get that meta downvotes mean disagreement, but I'm not sure what there is to disagree with in reporting suspicious behavior. I suspect the downvotes are actually more about my past policy discussions (like my stance on re-allowing ID questions) than the substance of this post.

@NapoleonWilson - It seems a fair question. If you're downvoting it, then you can be encouraged to explain why.

@Valorum And in your decade of SE experience, when has asking downvoters for their reason ever been a fruitful endeavour. ;-)

@galacticninja I can only speak from experience (neither did I call it that). I've seen this pattern myriads of times on meta. If a user becomes very omnipresent (as also informed by a general lack of meta activity by many other users) and when people regularly tend to disagree with his agenda, then the community can get tired of their constant presence. This happens with trolls as much as it does with users who have genuine concerns and bring up reasonable issues. And when every downvote is then accompanied by begs for explanations, this can add into that, too. That's just humans for ya.

@galacticninja "I suspect the downvotes are actually more about my past policy discussions (like my stance on re-allowing ID questions) than the substance of this post." - That is in fact pretty much exactly what I'm saying. You seem to agree then that the downvotes on this post likely haven't much to do with the issue itself (making your question for the reasons rather moot to begin with).

All of this, however, is also not the end of the world. It should be clear that many users either agree with your meta posts or at least don't hold a grudge against you for them. This thing is at +9 afterall. If anything it is merely a call to just not worry about it all that much. Downvotes happen and even more so on meta, including on good and reasonable posts. That is in fact why not getting all too fussed about votes on meta is generally a good idea. The "consensus" here clearly isn't that a quarter of the community condones suspicious voting patterns. ;-)

@NapoleonWilson "You seem to agree then that the downvotes on this post likely haven't much to do with the issue itself." I suspect that's true, but I'm not entirely sure. I also suspect that the downvotes are a reaction to being called out for what looks like a pattern of voting abuse. Of course, it's entirely possible I'm wrong, and there's a valid reason for disagreeing with this post that I'm not seeing. That's why I'm genuinely curious—sometimes people just need a little nudge to share their perspective.
